# Can I have a WCF call that hits the DB use the creds of the caller?

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config, impersonation

I have read a lot about impersonation, and I have tried a ton of tags in my config file.  I have tried `[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]` on my method that hits the database.

None of it works.  I get a wide variety of error messages depending on how my config is setup.

Can anyone lay out for me what C# and configuration (ie bindings, behaviors, endpoints settings) is needed to get the following scenario to work:

- I call a WCF method via WCFTestClient.
- The WCF Method is hosted in IIS (running under an IIS user that is not a valid user in the DB).
- That method sees who the caller is and passes those credentials on to the call to the database
- The Call to the database is in a different project (a class library) and uses Linq-to-sql
- The database performs the action as if the caller of the WCF service had done it.

If anyone has clarified this mystery please share the details with me.

Thanks!

(NOTE: I am developing in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and hosting in IIS 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice walkthrough of how to set up [impersonation in WCF here](http://geekswithblogs.net/claeyskurt/archive/2009/04/03/130723.aspx).  You may be missing the `servicebehavior` setting?